# query outside the for loop

Tags: apex, community

I am trying to query outside the for loop . But i have no idea do that process .I shared the code below.

```
public class OpportunityEmailNotification1 implements  Database.Batchable<SObject> {

    public void execute(SchedulableContext context) 
    {
      Database.executeBatch(this);
    }


public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {

    return Database.getQueryLocator(  [SELECT Id,name,ownerid,accountID, Channel_Partner_KAM_Email__c,Channel_Partner_Manager__c,CloseDate,
                                        Account.KAM__r.email,  Account.TL_for_Integration__r.email,
                                        Account.SAM_for_Integration__r.email ,RecordType.Developername
                                        FROM opportunity  where Status__c =:'Open']);


    }



    public static Map<String,Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> createDummyEmail(EmailTemplate templateName, List<String> whatIds){
    //  templateId  must be ID of an Email template
    //  targetObjId must be a Contact Id -- also used in merge fields of template recipient.xxxx
    //  whatId      must be an SObject that is used in the merge fields of the template relatedTo.xxxx
    //  fromId      if non null, use current user, otherwise, use this ID (most likely an org wide no reply id)
    Contact cnt = [Select Id, FirstName, Email From Contact Where Email != Null LIMIT 1];


   Map<String,  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> oppEmail = new   Map<String,    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();   
   List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> msgList= new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>(); 

   //system.debug('%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%'+mapKam);
   for(String whatID :whatIds){
     opportunity  oppti  = [SELECT Id,name,ownerid,accountID, Channel_Partner_KAM_Email__c,Channel_Partner_Manager__c,CloseDate,
                                        Account.KAM__r.email,  Account.TL_for_Integration__r.email,
                                        Account.SAM_for_Integration__r.email from opportunity where id =:whatID ]; 
    list<String> ccTo = new list<String>();    

   // system.drbug('&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&'+whatIds.get(whatID));
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();  
    user u =[select email from user where id =:oppti.ownerId];      
    msg.setTemplateId(templateName.id );
    msg.setWhatId(whatID);
    msg.setTargetObjectId(cnt.id);
    ccTo.add(oppti.Account.KAM__r.email);
    ccTo.add(oppti.Account.TL_for_Integration__r.email);
    ccTo.add(oppti.Account.SAM_for_Integration__r.email); 
    ccTo.add(u.email);
    msg.setToAddresses(ccTo);
   // msg.setToAddresses(new List<String>{[Select Email From User where name=:'narendra jagwan'].Email});

    msgList.add(msg);
  oppEmail.put(whatID, msg );   
   }      
    // Send the emails in a transaction, then roll it back
   Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
    Messaging.sendEmail(msgList); // Dummy email send
    Database.rollback(sp); // Email will not send as it is rolled Back
    // Send Actual email  
    system.debug(':::::::::::SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS:::::::::::'+oppEmail);
 List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> EmailList= new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();     
    String body ='';
    String Subject ='';
    list<string> sender = new list<String>();
   for(id key :oppEmail.keyset()){
     Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg1 = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
     body=oppEmail.get(key).getPlainTextBody();
     Subject =oppEmail.get(key).getSubject();
     sender =oppEmail.get(key).getToAddresses();
     system.debug('*********subject*********'+oppEmail.get(key).getsubject());
     msg1.setSubject(Subject);
     msg1.setPlainTextBody(body);
     msg1.setToAddresses(sender);
     EmailList.add(msg1);
   } 
    Messaging.sendEmail(EmailList);
    return null ;
}  


public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, list<opportunity> records) {
    list <String> testString = new list<String>();

     id oppID;       
     String ChannelKAMEmail ;
     String ChannelPartnerEmail ;
     date closerDate;  

     Contact cnt = [select id from Contact  limit 1];
     system.debug('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'+cnt );  
     EmailTemplate em =[SELECT Id  FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = 'CP - Opportunity Expected Closure date Alert'];

     system.debug('TTTTTTTT'+em );
     system.debug('AAAAAAAAAAAAA'+records); 
     for(opportunity  opp :records){
         oppID= opp.id;
         closerDate= opp.CloseDate ; 
         if(Date.Today() == closerDate-1|| Date.Today() ==closerDate-3 || Date.Today()==closerDate-5){  
           testString.add(oppID);    
          }
      }
       createDummyEmail( em , testString);



}
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    // No need to do anything, but this needs to be here

}   
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the for loop with the following:

```
for(opportunity oppti: [SELECT Id,name,ownerid,accountID, Channel_Partner_KAM_Email__c,Channel_Partner_Manager__c,CloseDate,
                                   Account.KAM__r.email,  Account.TL_for_Integration__r.email,
                                   Account.SAM_for_Integration__r.email from opportunity where id IN: whatIds ]){
            list<String> ccTo = new list<String>();    

            // system.drbug('&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&'+whatIds.get(whatID));
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();  
            user u =[select email from user where id =:oppti.ownerId];      
            msg.setTemplateId(templateName.id );
            msg.setWhatId(oppti.id);
            msg.setTargetObjectId(cnt.id);
            ccTo.add(oppti.Account.KAM__r.email);
            ccTo.add(oppti.Account.TL_for_Integration__r.email);
            ccTo.add(oppti.Account.SAM_for_Integration__r.email); 
            ccTo.add(u.email);
            msg.setToAddresses(ccTo);
            // msg.setToAddresses(new List<String>{[Select Email From User where name=:'narendra jagwan'].Email});

            msgList.add(msg);
            oppEmail.put(oppti.id, msg );   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this and move the query to the users outside of the loop as well.

```
//Query the opportunities


List<Opportunity> opportunities = [SELECT Id,name,ownerid,accountID, Channel_Partner_KAM_Email__c,Channel_Partner_Manager__c,CloseDate, Account.KAM__r.email,  Account.TL_for_Integration__r.email, Account.SAM_for_Integration__r.email from opportunity where id in :whatIds ];

// Sort them by Id
Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsById = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(opportunities);

//Get the ownerIds from the opportunities
Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();
for( Opportunity opp : opportunities )
  ownerIds.add(opp.ownerId);

// Get the Users
List<User> users = [select email from user where id in :ownerIds];

// Sort the emails by User Id
Map<Id, String> emailsByUserId = new Map<Id, String>();
for( User u : users )
{
  if( !emailsByUserId.keySet().contains( u.Id ) )
    emailsByUserId.put( u.Id, u.email );
}


// now the for loop can become like this
for( String whatId : whatIds )
{
  Opportunity opp = oppsById.get( whatId );
  String userEmail = emailsByUserId( opp.ownerId );

  list<String> ccTo = new list<String>();

  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();      
  msg.setTemplateId(templateName.id );
  msg.setWhatId(whatID);
  msg.setTargetObjectId(cnt.id);
  ccTo.add(opp.Account.KAM__r.email);
  ccTo.add(opp.Account.TL_for_Integration__r.email);
  ccTo.add(opp.Account.SAM_for_Integration__r.email); 
  ccTo.add(userEmail);
  msg.setToAddresses(ccTo);      
}
```